# Simple and effective way to stall a program

Tags: c, winapi

I have a program that sets a global keyboard hook and handles key presses. This is my WinMain:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  MSG msg;
  logFile = fopen("C:\\keylog.txt", "w");
  hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)KeyEvent, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);

  GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);

  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyHook);
  fclose(logFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Since it doesn't create any windows it won't ever receive a window message, so GetMessage would stall the program, and it is very light on CPU cycles. However, when it detects a certain key is pressed I want it to exit the program. I can't broadcast a message because it won't receive it. If I do something like:

```
while(State == true)
  Sleep(500);
```

The program itself and the global hook would stall and this is undesirable. Making it Sleep(0) makes it consume an unmanageable amount of CPU cycles.

So, what is the best alternative for my problem? The only thing I can think of is going through the trouble to register my own window class and create a window to receive the message, but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: you can always set it to Sleep(10). Which is infinitely better than no Sleep, or Sleep(0), yet it is very responsive.

Comment: It will probably be a lot easier if you just registered a window. In future, if you do decide to extend the functionality, things could get messy with inter process communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't broadcast a message using `HWND_BROADCAST`.

You don't need a window to receive messages.  However, if you had some way to publish your thread id, then [PostThreadMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(VS.85).aspx) could be used to send a message (probably a `WM_QUIT`) to your app.

Comment: Wait.. What? Don't you need a message queue to exist in the receiving thread to receive messages? Why would a console app have a message queue?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. it wouldn't normally. But no matter. A message queue is created on demand as soon as a message queue API is called: GetMessage() for example will ensure there is a message queue associated with the thread.

Answer (score 4):

Why not create synchronization object (maybe Event) and replace `GetMessage` with `WaitForSingleObject`?
You can easily make your keyboard hook routine trigger the object and your app will do the pre-termination stuff.

Comment: Won't work; per MSDN, LL keyboard hooks execute on the thread that install it and require a message loop; any Wait... function (except MsgWait) will block without processing the hooked messages.